# PostgreSQL convert column_1 text[] type to column_2 json type

Tags: json, postgresql

1. Is there a reasonably simple approach to copy `column_1` (data type t`text[]`) to `column_2` (data type JSON)?

...or...

2. Is there a reasonably simple approach to directly convert a column's data type *from* `text[]` *to* `JSON`?

---

The table `parts_bak1` I'm working with has two columns named `material_size` (`text[]`) and `material_size_json` (json).

I tried directly converting the column the following:

```
ALTER TABLE parts_bak1 ALTER COLUMN material_size TYPE JSON USING material_size::text[];
```

> ERROR:  column "material_size" cannot be cast automatically t
>
> HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.

I'm not sure how or even *if* I should approach the challenge using `USING`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is welcome, this *seems* to work:

```
UPDATE parts_bak1
SET material_size_json = subq.material_size 
FROM (SELECT id, array_to_json(material_size) AS material_size FROM parts_bak1) AS subq
WHERE parts_bak1.id=subq.id;
```